# How to set DNS and edit etc/resolv.conf on Ubuntu server 16.04?

Tags: networking, server, dns

I've got a VPS and I can't use `curl`, `ping`, etc. So I asked VPS support what's my problem and he said you should set DNS properly in etc/resolv.conf and configure nameservers.

Thus my question is how should I edit it and know what the nameservers are?

Maybe my question pretends silly but I'm newbie to Ubuntu and network.
So I appreciate any response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Nameservers play an essential role in directing traffic on the Internet by helping to connect your domain name with the IP address of your web server. To do this, they help web browsers and other services access your domain's DNS records.

From this [link](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-domain-name-service-dns#:%7E:text=Domain%20Name%20Service%20(DNS)%20is,(FQDN)%20to%20one%20another.&text=Computers%20that%20run%20DNS%20are,a%20name%20server%20on%20Linux.)

To edit `/etc/resolv.conf` the file will be overwritten by the system, but it's still possible to edit `/etc/resolv.conf`

First to install resolvconf with:

```
sudo apt install resolvconf
```

Edit the `/etc/resolv.conf`, you can remove lines or add lines, this is a example of a nameserver line:

```
nameserver x.x.x.x # x.x.x.x can be like 8.8.8.8(chrome's DNS)
```

Then edit the file `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` and add the lines from `/etc/resolv.conf` you edited. Finally you run:

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Comment: @yangmandi Really great help. Thank you.